# Repeated temporary irresponsiveness

Tags: associations

When working with a quite big nested Association (Depth reports 6, ByteCount about 7MB), Mathematica v.11.0.1 (Win 7 64b & 32b, 8.1 64b) repeatedly becomes irresponsive, indicating "Not Responding" in the upper window bar.  This state is temporary only; after about 10-20 seconds Mathematica will recover. It seems that these "blackouts" occur particularly after attempts to select a code with a mouse, or after cursor movement.  It has never crashed however.  Everything works fine otherwise, but the repeated interrupts are extremely annoying and obstructive. Sometimes it seems that it stopped, but after a while "breathing" resumes.  I am not aware of any use of dynamic features.

Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Does `MaxMemoryUsed[]` approach you available RAM?

Comment: No, MaxMemoryUsed[] reports about 60MB.

Comment: Does this happen when you use `;` after your expression to prevent print out to the front end?

Comment: The behavior described starts _immediately_ after Get'ting the `*.wl` package (or `*.mx` package dump) that contain the `Association`. And again I emphasize everything works perfectly (Queries on the `Association`, searching, extracting data, formatting using Dataset, ...) with one exception - periodic temporary freezing _without a single crash_.

Comment: Then I don't know. Questions like this aren't often posted to the SE forums, and you may wish to contact Wolfram Support if this remains an issue instead.

Comment: Two of my colleagues and I are getting a lot of "Not Responding" freezes.  More on 11.0 and still some on 11.1.1 running on Windows 7 & 10.  Sometimes just on notebook copy & paste.  Fair size code blocks.  Copies from older notebooks seems to give problems.